# ionic2 - ScreenOrientation

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic2

I want to lock my screen orientation to landscape at particular page in my `ionic2` app. So I import [the plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/screen-orientation/) from ionic site and `Cordova` screen orientation [plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation) too:

```
import { ScreenOrientation } from 'ionic-native';
```

Then I tried call it in my `constructor`:

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public orientation:ScreenOrientation
              ) {
                ScreenOrientation.lockOrientation('Landscape');
              }
```

But I got this error:

> EXCEPTION: Error in ./Test class Test_Host - inline template:0:0
>   caused by: No provider for ScreenOrientation!

What seems to be the issue here?

Comment: constructor is for dependency injection of providers.. the plugin is accesses through global object..

Comment: Where should I call the function `ScreenOrientation.lockOrientation('Landscape');`? I tried various places and it give me compile warning.

Comment: what is the warning? generally you place plugin the constructor within `this.platform.ready

Answer (score 10):

The error is stating there is no provider available for the ScreenOrientation "service".  In order to use these providers they must first be declared in app.module.ts.

To add ScreenOrientation to your list of providers in app.module.ts:

1. First add the import:
   `import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation';`
2. Then add ScreenOrientation to your list of providers in @NgModule:
   `providers: [
   StatusBar,
   SplashScreen,
   ScreenOrientation,
   {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
   ]`

Answer (score 0):

Delete the parameter “public orientation:ScreenOrientation” from the constructor function.